# When will NSURLConnection be rejected? (Not just deprecated)

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, deprecated

I have an app I wish to submit soon, and I don't have the time to rewrite any code. It uses `NSURLConnection` because when it was first written, that was used in Apple's demo code. (And still is last I looked.)

I understand that it is deprecated in favor of `NSURLSession` but it will be a wrenching pull-up-the-guts to rewrite. Can I avoid it for one more OS?

Comment: At WWDC 2016, they said "Now, we encouraged you then [in 2013], we continue to encourage you now to move your networking code to the `NSURLSession` API in your applications today and apps that you're going to be developing in the future." So, I read "encourage" to suggest that `NSURLSession` is not a hard requirement (but it's been three years now, so that's a bit crazy). The only hard requirement I know of is IPV6-only networks: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr - It will probably never lead to a rejection.

`NSURLConnection` was only deprecated since iOS 9.0. Don't even think about it until your app's Deployment Target is iOS 9.0 or later.

Even if your Deployment Target is already iOS 9.0 or later, it is still safe to use.

There are APIs deprecated since iOS 2.0 that can still be used.

There are many, many thousands of apps in the App Store that haven't been updated in years that still use `NSURLConnection`. Those apps will continue to work for several years to come.

There have been extremely few deprecated APIs over the years that don't still work several iOS versions later.

I'd feel safe using `NSURLConnection` for a few more years if required. But plan on replacing its use in the next year. Its replacement is much better.